# How do I make it so the bot can search discriminators all over discord and not only the same server?

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a bot that searches the same discriminatorsall over discord and not only the same server. How do I that. Also tell me if there is anything wrong with my code

````js
if ((message.author === client.user) && (message.content.substring(0, 2) === "%%")) {
        

    let msg = message.content.substring(2).split(" ");

    let cmd = msg[0];
    let args = msg.slice(1);

    if (cmd === "discrim") {
            

        let matches = [];

        let users = client.users.array() // online users in same server as client

        for (let user of users) {
            if (user.discriminator === args[0]) {   matches.push(user.username+"#"+args[0]); // full tag
            }
        }

            

        if (matches.length === 0) {
            message.channel.send("No matches found.");
        } else {
            let reply = "```" + matches.join("\n") + "```";

            reply += " Sample size: " + users.length; // number of users checked


            message.channel.send(reply);
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: `client.guilds.cache` will return all of the guilds, then you just need to look in every guild using a .forEach()

Answer (score 0):

`discord.js` does not have any data for users that are not in at least one of the same guilds as the bot.

To get all users the bot has data for, you can use:

```js
client.users.cache.find(user => user.discriminator === args[0])
```